# Почему не получается вставить смайлик?

Tags: mysql

При попытке сохранить в текстовое поле юникодный смайлик, например такой:  падает ошибка `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80' for column 'message' at row 1`. При этом специально для таблицы сделал `CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Вроде так это должно работать, но нет...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код, где и как вы пытаетесь сохранить его (в том числе код подключения к базе, это может быть важно)

Comment: @andreymal ну у меня есть только конфиг: https://shorturl.at/muFM4 Остальное выполняет фреймворк (Yii2). Запрос такой выполняется (он есть в сообщении об ошибке): INSERT INTO `chat_messages` (`room_id`, `user_id`, `message`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 4, '', NOW(), NOW())

Comment: Вот значит в конфиге и поменяйте `utf8` на `utf8mb4`

Comment: Покажите вывод `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'` и `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%'`. Добавьте в текст вопроса, а не комментарием.

Comment: @Akina https://tinyurl.com/yf5k58ym https://shorturl.at/cstEW нет смысла пихать это в вопрос. Будет непонятно.

Comment: Ну да... а давать ссылку на скриншот хрен знает где, да к тому же откуда этот скриншот может в любой момент испариться - это несомненно наполнено смыслом.

Comment: @Akina в смысле "хрень знает"? Ну дал же скриншот. Как вам его еще переслать? Сейчас вставлю в текст вопроса. Не понимаю что от этого изменится.

Comment: *Сейчас вставлю в текст вопроса. Не понимаю что от этого изменится.* Вот как раз ничего НЕ изменится со временем. И через 10 лет вопрос будет выглядеть как сейчас. Тогда как наличие через 10 лет скриншота по ссылке достаточно сомнительно.

Comment: Все настройки MySQL-сервера и соединения - в порядке. Так что проблема явно на клиенте - например, неверный codepage.